# displaying name of fk instead of numeric value through datatables in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatable, foreign-keys

i'm using datatables to display important details of tours but when i use select query it displaying fk integer value instead i want there type name which are in tour_standered table

My table images are as follows

[image: customize tours]

[image: tour standard]

**Model Function**

```
public function cust_tour_primary_data(){
    $this->db->select('');
    $this->db->from('customized_tours');
    $this->db->join('tour_standered', 'tour_standered.std_id =customized_tours.std_type','left');
    $res=$this->db->get();
    //return $res->result();
    print_r($res->result());
    echo $this->db->last_query();
}
```

By above function i'm able to get name of fk but i don't want other fields of tour_standered like created,deleted etc.
and i want do the same for other fk values. by doing so query result will be too long and bit confusing and i also don't know how to do multiple join.

Comment: just add in select query what thing you need to get from the table

Comment: thx it works, but there must be all unique name in all joining table, i got that error id ambiguity so i changed that name now it is working fine

Comment: use alias for same name columns @shivakumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the filed names you need in the select method, for eg:

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date');
```

will only select title, content and date from the table (refer : [Codeigniter active record](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select))

You can join multiple tables , the same way as you have done for the first table, for eg:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');
$this->db->join('user', 'user.id = blogs.user_id');
```

The above query joins 'blogs','comments' and 'user' table.

Comment: ya it works for me. please help to understand left join and simple join.